# C - Weird characters are printed out

Tags: c

I have written a small program that is going to become a text editor in the console for windows. This is what I have written right now:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int space = 20;
    int used = 0;
    int key = 0;
    char* text = malloc(sizeof(char) * space);

    while (key != 27)
    {
        if (used >= space)
        {
            space += 20;
            text = realloc(text, space);
        }

        key = getch();
        if (key == 8)
        {
            used--;
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
            {
                putch(text[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            used++;

            text[used] = key;
            putch(text[used]);
        }
    }

    free(text);
    return 0;
}
```

The printing when I press on letters at the keyboard works fine. The problem is when I hit backspace and try to remove a character. It starts printing random 'I' characters in the text I have written. What mistake am I making and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you properly handling non-alphanumerical keypresses?

Comment: Note: Suspect off by 1: `if (used >= space) ... used++;  text[used] = key;` on memory usage.  Suggest `text[used] = key;` then `used++`.

Comment: when using realloc(), always place the returned value in a temp pointer.  check(!=NULL) that temp pointer and if != NULL, then copy the temp pointer to the permanent pointer.   This is because if the realloc fails, and the assignment is directly into the permanent pointer, then the pointer to the previously allocated memory will be lost/overwritten, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: when calling malloc() or realloc() or calloc(), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the header file: 'conio.h' is not portable and does not exist in more C implementations.  Suggest removing the '#include <conio.h>'  and replacing getch() with getchar() and replacing putch() with putc()  As those system functions are prototyped in stdio.h

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the code, such as 27 and 20.  strongly suggest #define each of those values with meaningful names and use the meaningful names in the code.

Comment: why include 'windows.h' when none of the functions from windows.h are used?

Comment: the posted code has a major bug, when a newline is entered and then a backspace key is touched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off by one error.  Change

```
used++;
text[used] = key;
```

to

```
text[used] = key;
...
used++;
```

Some style notes:

First, use character literals instead of raw numeric codes; for example, instead of writing

```
if (key == 8)
```

use

```
if (key == '\b')
```

Where there isn't a predefined character literal (such as for the escape character) create a symbolic constant and use that:

```
#define ESC 27
...
while (key != ESC)
```

This will make your code a bit easier to understand for others.

Secondly, be careful with `realloc`; if it can't satisfy the request, it will return NULL.  If you assign that NULL value to your `text` pointer, you will lose your only reference to the memory you had already allocated.  It's better to do something like the following:

```
char *tmp = realloc( text, space + 20 );
if ( tmp )
{
  text = tmp;
  space += 20;
}
```

This way, if the `realloc` fails, you still have your reference to the previously allocated memory, allowing you to `free` it cleanly, or to recover from the error somehow.

Answer (score 1):

`text[0]` is never assigned. First time `text[used]` is written the `used` is already `1`, because it is getting incremented before. But on `backspace` you are printing `text` starting from `0`, which is uninitialized and containing garbage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the only problem, but one problem I can see in first look - the increase of 'used' is before the inserting (means - you start inserting to text[1]) and the reprintig starts from zero (means - you start printing with text[0]) the first value is fertilized.

Sorry for the bad english and hope It's help.

Answer (score 1):

the following code still has the 'off-by-one' error,

the following code needs the error checking added for
the calls to malloc() and realloc().

however, it is portable, compiles cleanly, and performs the desired functionality without outputting trash characters.

However, it still has the logic problem with newlines.

```
//#include <Windows.h>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int space = 20;
    int used = 0;
    int key = 0;
    char* text = malloc(sizeof(char) * space);

    while (key != 27) // escape
    {
        if (used >= space)
        {
            space += 20;
            text = realloc(text, space);
        }

        key = getchar();
        if (key == 8) // backspace
        {
            used--;
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
            {
                putc(text[i], stdout);
            }
        }
        else
        { // all other key strokes
            used++;

            text[used] = key;
            putc(text[used], stdout);
        }
    } // end while

    free(text);
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```